# Call keycloak token endpoint from REST endpoint

Tags: keycloak

I have a custom implementation of direct grant authenticator and want to call it using a custom rest end point. Is there any way to achieve this in Keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a REST endpoint for example /mycostumendpoint that calls keycloak's /token endpoint. The authenticator you implemented you have to put it as your keycloak's direct grant flow.

Comment: Yes but which method to call? Do you mean I make a POST call from custom end point? I was hoping to have a method that can be called from the REST endpoint

Comment: You wish to call what REST endpoint? Can you explain more your needs?